# Adding metadata information to imagery in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, imagery, metadata, worldview-2, sensormodel

I am working with imagery in ArcGIS Pro 2.8, and the data is World View 3.

What I am trying to achieve is to use the Mensuration tools available under the mensuration sub-group in the imagery tab in Pro.

[image]

I know that there are a few requirements to use all the tools available. I am concerned about the height measurement tools in the 2D category. Now the tools are only available when the imagery metadata contains information like the sensor info and sun angle.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/imagery/making-measurements-using-imagery.htm

[image]

Moving ahead I tried creating a mosaic dataset so that I can manually decide the product definition(World View 3) in this case. And also set the properties of the created mosaic dataset to allow calculating base heights.

[image]

This successfully enabled the other measuring tools, but it does not work as it is missing the sensor and the sun angle information.

[image]

Is there a way to embed or add the metadata information about the sensor and sun angle to successfully use the tools?